# Timing system call with ltrace: Adding `syscall` + `clock_gettime`?

Tags: linux, system-calls, strace, ltrace

I'm looking for some clarity in terms of the system calls. I tried avoiding the vDSO by calling a system call `clock_gettime` directly. Here is a snippet of a program named `sys_clock_gettime`.

```c
int clock = CLOCK_MONOTONIC;
struct timespec ts;
if (syscall(__NR_clock_gettime, clock, &ts) == -1){
  exit(-1); 
}
```

This program takes the name of a clock (`CLOCK_BOOTTIME, CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, etc...) and a number of calls to make. For instance, the snippet below would make 100 calls to `clock_gettime` for the `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` clock.

```
./sys_clock_gettime CLOCK_BOOTTIME 100
```

I tried using `ltrace` to figure out what was going on:

```
ltrace -cS ./sys_clock_gettime CLOCK_BOOTTIME 100
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls      function
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
 77.41    0.006887          68       100 syscall
 14.32    0.001274          12       100 clock_gettime
  1.79    0.000159         159         1 brk
  1.17    0.000104         104         1 exit
  1.16    0.000103          51         2 strcmp
  0.82    0.000073          14         5 mmap
  0.65    0.000058          14         4 mprotect
  0.61    0.000054          54         1 exit_group
  0.51    0.000045          45         1 atoi
  0.31    0.000028          14         2 openat
  0.30    0.000027          13         2 fstat
  0.29    0.000026          13         2 close
  0.19    0.000017          17         1 munmap
  0.17    0.000015          15         1 access
  0.16    0.000014          14         1 read
  0.15    0.000013          13         1 arch_prctl
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
100.00    0.008897                   225 total
```

For some reason there is a `syscall` entry as well as a `clock_gettime` entry. You can tell that the `syscall` is a library entry, while `clock_gettime` is a system call entry because if you disable the `-S` mode in `ltrace` it won't show up. If I'm interested in timing the execution of the system call, should I be adding the `syscall` and `clock_gettime` information? For some reason, this only happened when I ran this in Amazon Linux 2, when running in an Ubuntu VM in my own computer, I only get a `SYS_clock_gettime` entry, as I was expecting.

Now, compare this with another program, let's call it `vdso_clock_gettime`, that takes the same arguments.

```
ltrace -cS ./vdso_clock_gettime CLOCK_BOOTTIME 100
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls      function
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
 85.82    0.004340          43       100 clock_gettime
  3.08    0.000156         156         1 brk
  2.02    0.000102          51         2 strcmp
  1.90    0.000096          96         1 exit
  1.38    0.000070          14         5 mmap
  1.13    0.000057          14         4 mprotect
  0.97    0.000049          49         1 exit_group
  0.93    0.000047          47         1 atoi
  0.59    0.000030          15         2 openat
  0.51    0.000026          13         2 fstat
  0.51    0.000026          13         2 close
  0.32    0.000016          16         1 access
  0.32    0.000016          16         1 munmap
  0.26    0.000013          13         1 read
  0.26    0.000013          13         1 arch_prctl
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
100.00    0.005057                   125 total
```

If I don't add the `syscall` and `clock_gettime` entries from the first program's output, then the total time required to call the system call `clock_gettime` is actually lower (12 usecs/call) than if I called the vDSO version (43 usecs/call) in the second program. That wouldn't make sense, in my opinion. It would only make sense if the first program's calls would take ~80 usecs/call (the addition of the two entries), as the vDSO is supposed to accelerate this.

I know that in this system (kernel 5.10), `clock_gettime` is accelerated via the vDSO, because when I run the snippet below, I get no output:

```
strace -e clock_gettime,gettimeofday -- date >/dev/null
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the clock source is set to `tsc`. Any ideas of what is going on here?

**Edit:** Looking at the actual trace, I am starting to thing that the call to `syscall` includes both.

```
syscall(228, 7, 0x7ffd270f9c80, 0x1999999999999999 <unfinished ...>
clock_gettime@SYS(7, 0x7ffd270f9c80, 0x1999999999999999, 0x7ffd270fa70a) = 0
<... syscall resumed> )
```

I also experimented with `nanosleep` and if I counted both the `syscall` and `nanosleep` calls, the time of sleep would double, and that wouldn't make sense. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect some of the confusion is down to naming. On my system, forcing a system call produces a trace in this style:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls      function
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
 84.10    0.005402          54       100 syscall
 10.14    0.000651           6       100 SYS_clock_gettime
  1.87    0.000120          17         7 SYS_mmap
  0.97    0.000062          62         1 SYS_brk
  0.72    0.000046          11         4 SYS_mprotect
  0.47    0.000030          30         1 SYS_access
  0.45    0.000029          29         1 SYS_read
  0.37    0.000024          12         2 SYS_fstat
  0.31    0.000020          10         2 SYS_openat
  0.26    0.000017          17         1 SYS_munmap
  0.23    0.000015           7         2 SYS_close
  0.11    0.000007           7         1 SYS_arch_prctl
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
100.00    0.006423                   222 total
```

Using the vDSO produces a trace in this style:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls      function
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
 93.17    0.004158          41       100 clock_gettime
  1.66    0.000074          74         1 SYS_access
  1.61    0.000072          10         7 SYS_mmap
  0.92    0.000041          10         4 SYS_mprotect
  0.72    0.000032          16         2 SYS_openat
  0.56    0.000025          25         1 SYS_brk
  0.36    0.000016           8         2 SYS_close
  0.34    0.000015           7         2 SYS_fstat
  0.34    0.000015          15         1 SYS_munmap
  0.18    0.000008           8         1 SYS_read
  0.16    0.000007           7         1 SYS_arch_prctl
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------------------
100.00    0.004463                   122 total
```

In the first case, the program calls the C library `syscall` function, which calls the `clock_gettime` system call; in the second case, the program calls the C library `clock_gettime` function, which calls the vDSO. The two `clock_gettime` calls are different, but they appear identical in your traces.

As I understand it, the time reported for `syscall` does include the time reported for `SYS_clock_gettime`; this also means that the percentage display is misleading. This isn’t covered in the documentation and I haven’t read all the source code so I may be wrong.

Another point to consider is that the times measured by `ltrace` include `ltrace`’s overhead. Other profiling tools such as `perf stat` show that the vDSO is indeed faster:

```
             42.13 msec task-clock                #    0.988 CPUs utilized          
                 4      context-switches          #    0.095 K/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
                44      page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec                  
       138,771,425      cycles                    #    3.294 GHz                      (71.53%)
        38,690,379      instructions              #    0.28  insn per cycle           (71.57%)
         7,599,904      branches                  #  180.377 M/sec                    (81.14%)
           300,729      branch-misses             #    3.96% of all branches          (75.76%)

       0.042636471 seconds time elapsed

       0.015510000 seconds user
       0.027143000 seconds sys
```

typically for the system call version (over 100,000 calls), and

```
              4.84 msec task-clock                #    0.815 CPUs utilized          
                 0      context-switches          #    0.000 K/sec                  
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
                48      page-faults               #    0.010 M/sec                  
         6,257,648      cycles                    #    1.294 GHz                      (50.28%)
         9,019,370      instructions              #    1.44  insn per cycle         
         1,925,045      branches                  #  398.113 M/sec                  
             1,594      branch-misses             #    0.08% of all branches          (49.72%)

       0.005934008 seconds time elapsed

       0.003025000 seconds user
       0.003025000 seconds sys
```

for the vDSO version.